# White spaces in the for loop in win batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, whitespace

I have the following loop in my Windows batch script

```
set Folder = %~1

for %%M in (d:\%Folder%\*.exe) do (
    set FileName = %%~nM
    echo !FileName!
)
```

When one of the Folder have spaces the %%M is has value till the first space.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "Folder=%~1"

for %%M in ("d:\%Folder%\*.exe") do (
    set "FileName=%%~nM"
    echo !ModuleName!
)
```

Don't know where the `ModuleName` comes from (I suppose you also have somewhere delayed expansion)...

! Do not use spaces around equal sign with set command otherwise the spaces will be included both int the variable name and its value !

In plain FOR loop you can put double quotes in the items that contain delimiters and to process them properly.